# make virtual host available through local network for iphone

Tags: iphone, mamp, virtualhost, router, portforwarding

I'm building a site on my localhost with a virtual host (mynewsite.com). Instead of uploading files to an actual server and I'd prefer to just test locally.  I have the virtual host working on my desktop, I just want it to be available so I can see it on my iPhone or any computer on my network.  So if I go to mynewsite.com on my iPhone it will display the site from my localhost.  I think I need to do port forwarding but I'm having difficulty figuring it out.  I'm on a Mac with MAMP.

How do I make the virtual host available to my iPhone through my Linksys router for testing?

My httpd.conf in MAMP looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jaysonp/Sites/mynewsite"
    ServerName "mynewsite.com"
    ServerAlias *.mynewsite.com
...
```

Then in my host file I have:
127.0.0.1 mynewsite.com

I should note that I can't just hit the ipaddress on my iPhone, there is code that checks against the domain name for the site to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11757977/598273). But basically, you just have to modify the Wifi settings in your iPad to use the IP address of your development machine as an HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use application to edit hosts file on the devices. Use iFile application. You can add more any hostname. You can see some picture here but I wrote in my language.

[http://www.anop72.info/iphoneipad-เรียก-url-vhost-ทำอย่างไร/](http://www.anop72.info/iphoneipad-%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B5%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%81-url-vhost-%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B3%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A2%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%87%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%A3/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change the `host file` of respective machine on which you want to see your virtual host.

For Example:

(in `Linux and macOS` ): `/etc/hosts` 
(in `Windows` ): `c:/windows/system32/drives/etc/hosts` 
(in `Android` ): Android is also the part of linux so the host file location is same in android too. But you need root access to change the host file.
(in `iOS` ): (anyone who knows can edit here!!)

Open the host file and

```
192.168.1.70    mynewsite.com
```

`192.168.1.70` is the ip address of the machine in which your project is running on a virtual hosting -> `mynewsite.com`

All of the other devices `must be` connected to the `same network` .

Answer (score -2):

Just use the IP address of your virtual host. If your iPhone is on the same local network as your [virtual] host - the IP address will work fine.

I am not quite sure how you are defining "virtual" host - i.e. are you using Xen or VMware or something - or just running a web service on your dekstop?

If it is the former - you need to set up the IP services through Xen/VMware - if it's the later - its you desktop machine's IP address.

Comment: I have the virtual host setup in my httpd.conf in MAMP.

Comment: Then two options: Make the default host point to your "mynewssite.com" and have your iPhone app use the IP address instead of the name. OR Run your own DNS Server - make that iPhone use it (either be setting your wireless router DHCP, or entering manually on the iPhone) - Make the DNS server resove "mynewsserver.com" to the the IP address of your Host.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still a bit confused.  It sounds like I need to run my own DNS server because I need use the domain name for the site.  Where am I setting the router DHCP? in the router admin?  And how do I make a DNS server resolve to "mynewserver.com"? Thanks.

Comment: Yes - your own DNS server. You can either set the DNS pointer in the route admin, or go into the WiFi settings on your iPhone, and for "IP Address" - specify "Static" - and put in all your settings manually - replacing "DNS" with your new server. Alternatively, you can run your own Web Proxy which uses special handing for "mynewsserver.com" - and set you iPhone to use it under the "HTTP Proxy" setting.